# How to debug Metal errors? (IOAF)

Tags: ios, runtime-error, metal

For the past year, every now and then, I've been getting IOAF error codes.
Mostly `IOAF code 3`, `IOAF code 3` and `IOAF code 5`.
They are very hard to debug...

I've solved some of them. It's usually something in my render pipeline.
Tho every time I encounter them, I need to start from scratch.

Is there a good way to approach debugging the generic and cryptic IOAF errors?

I've tried GPU frame capture, tho not shure where to look.

Building with Xcode 10 on macOS 10.14. Running on iOS 12 with iOS 10 minimum target.
This error usually happens on older devices like the iPad Mini 2. The iPhone X and iPad Pro don't really get these too often.

Comment: When these show up only with A7 chips (and there is no other error), it typically means the GPU just is not fast enough to render the frame in the given amount of time for the screen refresh rate. I have not seen these on A8 and newer chips, only A7 (this was the first 64 bit Apple chip and it is tragically slow).